# How to comprehend clause 10.5 in ECMA-262 5.1 Edition?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Recently I read about the ES5 Specification, there's one confusion in **Chapter-10** which is about **Execution Context**. More exactly, the confusion exists in 10.5[ https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5 ].

The clause 10.5 named **Declaration Binding Instantiation**, it explains how the component **VariableEnvironment** of **Execution Context** is generated.Where Im confused is **the item-5-iii**: " If existingProp .[[Configurable]] is true... ".

What's the purpose for this, **why the PropertyDescriptor.[[Value]] is undefined when call [[DefineOwnProperty]] of global object**, and how to prove this step with real javascript code?

Or maybe this is a mistake? Here the [[Value]] should be the declared function object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a function is declared on the top level, it checks to see if the property name exists on the global object first. If the property does not exist, then:

> c. Let funcAlreadyDeclared be the result of calling env’s HasBinding concrete method passing fn as the argument.
>
> d. If funcAlreadyDeclared is false, call env’s CreateMutableBinding concrete method passing fn and configurableBindings as the arguments.

Otherwise, it goes into the `e.` part that you're looking at:

> e. Else if env is the environment record component of the global environment then: ...

So, anywhere inside that `e.`, `funcAlreadyDeclared` will necessarily be `true` - the property *is* already defined, and what remains is to check to see if the property is changeable. The `PropertyDescriptor.[[Value]]` *will necessarily* return a full property descriptor, because inside `e.`, we know that the property does exist; that block only runs if `funcAlreadyDeclared` is `true`.

On the top level, it checks if the property is configurable, and if so, sets the associated property on the global object. Eg, `function foo(){}` on the top level will result in `window.foo` being defined, and this section checks that `window.foo` can be defined.

Having `configurable` of `true` [means](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description):

> true if and only if the type of this property descriptor may be changed and if the property may be deleted from the corresponding object.

For example, `window.top` is not configurable, so the `[[DefineOwnProperty]]` will not run:

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'top'));
```

So, trying to declare a function named `top` on the top level will throw an error:

```js
function top() {
}
```

Comment: Inside `e.`, when the property is configurable and then set the associated property on the global object with declared function, why the [[Value]] is not the function object?

Comment: For some reason, the specification separates out the defining of the property from the assignment of the value to the property. It's like it first creates the property with value `undefined`, and *then*, in `f.` (*Call env’s SetMutableBinding concrete method passing fn, fo, and strict as the arguments.*), assigns the function value.